# Self-referring association: N+1 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let say I have following Model:

```
class Strategy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :snapshots, :class_name => 'Strategy', :foreign_key => 'master_id'
  belongs_to :master, :class_name => 'Strategy', :counter_cache => :snapshots_count

  scope :master_only, -> { where(:master_id => nil) }
end
```

So any user can create a snapshot of a master-instance of `Strategy`

In controller I am getting all "master" instances of `Strategy` that belongs to `current_user`

```
@strategies = current_user.strategies.master_only.includes(:user,:snapshots)
```

Rails correctly loads `strategies` and `snapshots` in two queries but fetches `user` for each snapshot in separate query thus introducing N+1 issue (N+2 in this particular case):

```
Strategy Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `strategies`.* FROM `strategies` WHERE strategies`.`user_id` = 2 AND `strategies`.`master_id` IS NULL LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0   
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (2)   
Strategy Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `strategies`.* FROM `strategies` WHERE `strategies`.`master_id` IN (56, 8, 55, 1, 58, 57, 24, 22)   
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1   
....    
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way to load the snapshot user more effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a slight change to the way you include `:user` and `:snapshots` to only generate one query to load all the users that belong to the `:snapshots`:

```
@strategies = current_user.strategies.master_only.includes(snapshots: :user)
```

The generated SQL queries will be something like:

```
SELECT `strategies`.* FROM `strategies` WHERE strategies`.`user_id` = 2 AND `strategies`.`master_id` IS NULL LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0   
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (2)   
SELECT `strategies`.* FROM `strategies` WHERE `strategies`.`master_id` IN (56, 8, 55, 1, 58, 57, 24, 22)
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (2,5)
```

**UPDATE**

According to the OP, the following resolved the N+1 issue:

```
@strategies = current_user.strategies.master_only.includes(:user, snapshots: :user)
```

Comment: Great! I did not know that I can do `.includes(snapshots: :user)`. in the form you provided it does not change the resulted SQLs (N+1 is still happened) but this statement solved the issue: `@strategies = current_user.strategies.master_only.includes(:user, snapshots: :user)`. Can you please update your answer to reflect this, so I can accept it?